# how to avoid mixed content error in angular js mvc?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web, web-hosting

eror is
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website url' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://anotherurl'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('GISService', ['$resource', 'GISServiceURL', '$http', function($resource, GISServiceURL, $http) {
  return function(term) {
    return $resource(GISServiceURL + term, {}, {
      'GetAllAddresses': {
        method: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
      } // returns all matching addresses 
    });
  };
}]);
```

Comment: `https://anotherurl`, you can't use `http` resources on `https` sites without warnings.

Comment: there is a way to solve this problem and i am unable to get it!